# What keeps java processes alive after jar execution?

Tags: java, process

I have a java jar file which I am executing from the windows command prompt.  The code finishes normally (i.e. does what it is supposed to) but the java process continues to run.  The application is single threaded.  I need to hit Ctrl-c to stop the process after the code completes to get the command prompt back.

I assume that I could put a `System.exit(0)` at the end of my main method which would presumably fix this, but I was under the impression that it wasn't necessary.  Under what conditions are java processes kept alive at the end of execution?  Here's the shell of my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //application code here
        Logger.log("Now finished");
    } catch (SomeExceptoin e) {
        Logger.error("Some error occured");
    }
}
```

Where the logger is my own incredibly basic static class which just dumps messages to `System.out.println()`.  "Now finished" appears in the console, but the process continues to run.  Any ideas?

EDIT: As requested, here's the logger code in all its glory (I did warn you :)

```
public class Logger {
   public static void logInfo(String logMessage)
   {
      System.out.println(timestamp() + logMessage);
   }
   private static String timestamp()
   {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
      String timestamp = "[" + formatter.format(new Date()) + "] ";
      return timestamp;
   }
}
```

EDIT EDIT:  I put a finally block onto my try above with the thread dump code from the link in instanceofTom's answer.  Here's the output:

...
[2010.11.18 11:22:57] Output complete.  All processing now finished.

---

Thread name: Reference Handler 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)

---

Thread name: Finalizer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

---

Thread name: Signal Dispatcher

---

Thread name: Attach Listener

---

Thread name: Java2D Disposer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:125) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

---

Thread name: main 
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1436) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.visit(WorkloadManager.java:124) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.visit(WorkloadManager.java:138) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.main(WorkloadManager.java:71) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)

---

Thread name: com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)

---

Thread name: AWT-Windows 
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method) 
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:291) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

---

Thread name: EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
com.sun.java.accessibility.util.ComponentEvtDispatchThread.run(EventQueueMonitor.java:616) ******************************** 
Thread name: Reference Handler 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)

---

Thread name: Finalizer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

---

Thread name: Signal Dispatcher

---

Thread name: Attach Listener

---

Thread name: Java2D Disposer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:125) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

---

Thread name: main 
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1436) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.visit(WorkloadManager.java:124) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.visit(WorkloadManager.java:138) 
com.my.code.WorkloadManager.main(WorkloadManager.java:71) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)

---

Thread name: com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)

---

Thread name: AWT-Windows 
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method) 
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:291) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

---

Thread name: EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
com.sun.java.accessibility.util.ComponentEvtDispatchThread.run(EventQueueMonitor.java:616)

Comment: Does the java program call Runtime.exec() at all?

Comment: I would perhaps post the logger code also.  Somehow an orphaned thread has to be persisting.  I know of no other way for this to occur.

Comment: A frequent cause is additional, non-daemon threads. Although your code is single-threaded, are you positive that none of the things you're calling are creating non-daemon threads?

Comment: I agree with previous comments. You might try generating a thread-dump or using "jps" tool.

Comment: @izb - There is no call to Runtime.exec().

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer I suppose its possible one of the (relatively standard) 3rd party libraries I'm using does so.

Comment: did you accidently paste the threaddump twice? Threads seem to be posted twice, for instance "Java2D Disposer"

Comment: @matt b I don't think so, but I didn't look all that closely at the  code which dumps the threads, so possibly a bug in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java applications with a UI start event handling threads that are not "daemon" threads. That is, the program will not terminate as long as these threads are running—even if no windows are currently displayed.

Do you have an "Exit" command on your menu? Its `Action` should invoke `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: @Chris Knight - Your thread dump shows that there are AWT event threads running. It's possible that some library that you are using uses the graphics toolkit. For example, I've tried to use an SVG library server-side to generate images for a web app, but the app won't run on Google app engine because it requires AWT libraries internally.

Comment: good point.  I hadn't considered that.  Digging deeper I am using JFreeChart libraries to produce graphs which subsequently get output to disk, so no UI, but graphics libraries involved behind the scenes.  Sounds like this is it?

Comment: +1 Good catch based off of the added information with the thread dump.

Comment: @Chris Knight - That might be it. There has been a lot of work done to get smarter about automatically terminating the event dispatch thread, but depending on the version of Java you run, you might run into problems still. Googling, I found some reports that JFree chart webapps "sometimes" did not shutdown properly, but the issues were closed as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 2):

If everything in your code seems normal it is likely that there is an orphaned thread still running.

The code [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ListThreads.html) describes how to list all of the threads currently running in the JVM

Alternatively you could use a profiler or IDE with built-in profiler to view the running threads.

It would help in answering this question if you could let us know what threads are still running when your code is finished; *Even though your code may be single threaded there will likely still be other threads running in the JVM such as the garbage collection thread ( Although GC threads wont stop the JVM from exiting )*

Comment: Thread dump added to my question based on the code in your link being put as the last executable code in my main method.

Answer (score 2):

A Java process will remain alive so long as it has one or more non-daemon threads running.

Consider using JVisualVM located in the Java JDK's bin directory and attach it to your Java program. There you will be able to perform an analysis of active Threads and their state as well as perform a thread dump.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your thread dump, it looks like one of the Google libraries (perhaps Guice or Guava) is being loaded.

```
Thread name: com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132) 
com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)
```

If so, then this bug could be causing the issue:

- http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=92

It is related to the finalizer thread not being let go correctly.  There are various workarounds posted.

Comment: this could also be the reason (see erickson's post above and related comments) as I am using Guice for dependency injection. Thanks.